# Getting selected data from the multi select

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use flutter package 'multi_select_flutter'. The example they provided is for an old flutter version so I fixed that part as well. In my code everything works, but I need a way to get what items I selected. So I can put those data to firestore db.

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/multi_select_flutter.dart';

class EditRecPref extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditRecPref({super.key});

  @override
  State<EditRecPref> createState() => _EditRecPrefState();
}

class _EditRecPrefState extends State<EditRecPref> {
  static final List<Animal> _animals = [
    Animal(id: 1, name: "Lion"),
    Animal(id: 2, name: "Flamingo"),
    Animal(id: 3, name: "Hippo"),
    Animal(id: 4, name: "Horse"),
    Animal(id: 5, name: "Tiger"),
    Animal(id: 6, name: "Penguin"),
    Animal(id: 7, name: "Spider"),
    Animal(id: 8, name: "Snake"),
    Animal(id: 9, name: "Bear"),
    Animal(id: 10, name: "Beaver"),
    Animal(id: 11, name: "Cat"),
    Animal(id: 12, name: "Fish"),
    Animal(id: 13, name: "Rabbit"),
    Animal(id: 14, name: "Mouse"),
    Animal(id: 15, name: "Dog"),
    Animal(id: 16, name: "Zebra"),
    Animal(id: 17, name: "Cow"),
    Animal(id: 18, name: "Frog"),
    Animal(id: 19, name: "Blue Jay"),
    Animal(id: 20, name: "Moose"),
    Animal(id: 21, name: "Gecko"),
    Animal(id: 22, name: "Kangaroo"),
    Animal(id: 23, name: "Shark"),
    Animal(id: 24, name: "Crocodile"),
    Animal(id: 25, name: "Owl"),
    Animal(id: 26, name: "Dragonfly"),
    Animal(id: 27, name: "Dolphin"),
  ];

  final _items = _animals
      .map((animal) => MultiSelectItem<Animal>(animal, animal.name))
      .toList();

  List<Object?> _selectedAnimals2 = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                MultiSelectBottomSheetField(
                  initialChildSize: 0.4,
                  listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
                  searchable: true,
                  buttonText: const Text("Favorite Animals"),
                  title: const Text("Animals"),
                  items: _items,
                  onConfirm: (values) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedAnimals2 = values;
                      print(_selectedAnimals2);
                    });
                  },
                  chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                    onTap: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedAnimals2.remove(value);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                // const SizedBox(height: 20),
                _selectedAnimals2.isEmpty
                    ? Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: const Text(
                          "None selected",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                        ))
                    : Container(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Animal {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Animal({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
}
```

I tried even ,
`print(_selectedAnimals2);` .

turns out it just give me an output like,
`[Instance of 'Animal', Instance of 'Animal']`

Quick Update: Actually I learned there's inspect thing in flutter, so I used it. Actually you can inspect '_selectedAnimals2' and it shows data like this,

```
[0]:Animal
id:2
name:
"Flamingo"
hashCode:1028204706
runtimeType:Type (Animal)

[1]:Animal
id:3
name:"Hippo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instance of 'Animal', means that you are selecting an object of the class that you created called 'Animal'.

Every time you want to reference the data, you use the whole object, but if you want details, you need to use `_selectedAnimals2.name` or `_selectedAnimals2["name"]` to get the property you need.

If you need both the `Name`, and `ID`, the correct way to send the data between services is through `JSON`. So you need to convert your selected animal to a JSON format.

This can work both for reading and storing data.

Comment: Actually I still can't do that. For " _selectedAnimals2.name "

 "The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'List<Object?>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'name', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'."

And for _selectedAnimals2["name"] i get,
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'